# Updating the `URL` but not loading the path

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

Navbar route not working.

I have a `navbar component` which acts as a menu bar. This `navbar component` routes to an `About component`. I also have a `Route.js` where I have implementing routing for the rest of the app. `Route.js` is where I am loading `Navbar component`.

It is updating the `URL` but not loading the path.

[Complete code can be found here:](https://github.com/ntanwir10/react-trello-clone)

`Navbar component`

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Link,
} from "react-router-dom";

import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';

import About from '../pages/About';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    hr: {
        width: '0.5px',
        height: '25px',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        margin: '0px 10px',
    },
    a: {
        color: '#ffffff',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        textDecoration: 'none',
    },
});

const Navbar = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Router>
                <AppBar position="static" width='100%'>
                    <Toolbar>
                        <Typography variant="h6" >
                            <Link to='/' className={classes.a}> Todo List Application </Link>
                        </Typography>
                        <Divider orientation="vertical" className={classes.hr} />
                        <Link to='../pages/About.js' className={classes.a}>
                            About
                        </Link>
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
                <Route path="/about.js" component={About}>
                    <About />
                </Route>
            </Router>
        </Fragment>
    );
}

export default Navbar;
```

And this `AppRouter` is loaded in `App.js`

Comment: do you see the About component when directly editing the browser url to /about.js?
Also, you don't want to add .js extensions to your url paths as it looked awkward and dangerous, so I would suggest to just use /about

Comment: I have modified my code with the changes suggested below. but now, the problem is that it displays both `home component` and the `about component`. Check this screenshot. imgur.com/a/7x8tRX8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cloned your project and ran it.

Updated Navbar.js, (Removed Router enclosing from the AppBar and removed the Route declaration from the Navbar component)

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link} from "react-router-dom";

import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';

import About from '../pages/About';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    hr: {
        width: '0.5px',
        height: '25px',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        margin: '0px 10px',
    },
    a: {
        color: '#ffffff',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        textDecoration: 'none',
    },
});

const Navbar = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <Fragment>

                <AppBar position="static" width='100%'>
                    <Toolbar>
                        <Typography variant="h6" >
                            <Link to='/' className={classes.a}> Todo List Application </Link>
                        </Typography>
                        <Divider orientation="vertical" className={classes.hr} />
                        <Link to='/about' className={classes.a}>
                            About
                        </Link>
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>

        </Fragment>
    );
}

export default Navbar;
```

updated src/routes/index.js (added the about Route here and enclosed the Routes using Switch)

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import TrelloBoard from "../components/TrelloBoard";
import Home from "../components/Home";
import Navbar from "../components/navbar/Navbar";
import About from "../components/pages/About";

const AppRouter = () => {
    return (

        <Router>
            <div>
                <Navbar></Navbar>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
                    <Route path="/:boardID" component={TrelloBoard} />
                    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
};

export default AppRouter;
```

I think the above changes work as you expected.

Answer (score 2):

Your `<Link>` component need a argument `to` which is a define url for a define `<Route>` in your router.

In your example, it seams like you are trying to access a js file, using a relative path, but this is not how react-router-dom works.

Try replacing with :

```
<Link to='/about' className={classes.a}>
```

And make sure your your  you have the same route defined:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}>
    <Route path="/about">
        <About />
    </Route>
</Switch>
```

> A `<Switch>`  looks through all its children 
>        elements and renders the first one whose path
>        matches the current URL. Use a  any time
>        you have multiple routes, but you want only one
>        of them to render at a time

You can see a full working example on [react router basic documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic), which run this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-basic-bnpsd).

Comment: It works, but its displaying `home component` and the `about component`. Check this screenshot. https://imgur.com/a/7x8tRX8

Comment: Might come from your `/` route which  need a exact `<Route exact path="/">`

Comment: ok. but even if I remove `exact` from there, it still remains the same.